# onContentSizeChange not firing on height change on Android (react-native)

Tags: react-native

`onContentSizeChange` doesn't seem to fire properly on Android. Event is fired on `mount`, but isn't fired on `text height` change. Identical code works fine for iOS:

```
<TextInput
  editable = {true}
  multiline = {true}
  [...]
  onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
  this.setState({height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height});
  }}
  style={{height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}}
/>
```

Comment: What version of React Native are you using? This is working for me in v0.46.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6552#issuecomment-269989962

In Android `onContentSizeChange` is called only once
use `onChange` instead of `onContentSizeChange`.

**Code**

```
<TextInput
  editable = {true}
  multiline = {true}
  [...]
  onChange={(event) => {
  this.setState({height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height});
  }}
  style={{height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}}
/>
```

Comment: This is no longer a good workaround, it's deprecated: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/bac84ce207a0466cec95626131063751eb48b964

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `value` after each change fixed the problem for me

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    this.setState({text});
  }}
  onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
    this.setState({height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height});
  }}
  style={{height: this.state.height}}
  value={this.state.text}
/>
```